# Cacheable Docker image for Azure Container Instances

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-service, azure-container-registry, azure-container-instances

I'm trying to use Azure Container Instances and I have a problem with **long** pulls of my image. It takes about 3 minutes for ACI to pull my image.

I've checked the [Troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting#container-takes-a-long-time-to-start) which says the following:

> To ensure the fastest Windows container startup time, use one of the three most recent versions of the following two images as the base image:
>   `microsoft/windowsservercore` or `microsoft/nanoserver`

My image is pretty simple and based of `microsoft/windowsservercore:ltsc2016` as suggested in the Troubleshooting guide. Here is the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/cirruslabs/docker-images-windows/blob/master/windowsservercore/Dockerfile) and [`cirrusci/windowsservercore:2016` image itself](https://hub.docker.com/r/cirrusci/windowsservercore/).

I can see that if I just try to start `microsoft/windowsservercore:ltsc2016`, it takes just about 20 seconds to start it. So my guess is that `microsoft/windowsservercore:ltsc2016` is really cached but just not the latest digest as the documentation claims. I wonder if there is any way to find out exact digests of images that ACI caches?

*Note:* I've tried to move the image from Docker Hub to Azure Container Registry in the same region as [suggested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting#image-location). It didn't help much. It was still around 3 minutes to pull the image.

Comment: This is a known issue with various people asking for caching. No feedback as to when/if this is going to happen though  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602224-azure-container-instances/suggestions/31660276-cache-the-downloaded-container-image-in-the-contai

Answer (score 2):

So if you comment out the Powershell part of your Dockerfile, so it creates a container with no changes from the base, does that pull in 20 seconds or 3 mins?

If it pulls in 20 seconds then it is just your file system changes that are causing the slowdown, but if it takes 3 mins then that would prove that Azure has some cached containers ready to go and you might be better off spinning up one of those base containers, and then calling your powershell script directly onto it. It looks like that script would run pretty quickly.

That will also save you from having a registry at all.

Comment: I was able to minimize the image to only have one layer on top of `microsoft/windowsservercore:ltsc2016` which is 400Mb. In this case it's still pulling for almost 90 seconds (3 minutes initially was with several layers on top of `microsoft/windowsservercore:ltsc2016`). It's much better but still seems a bit too slow for me.

Comment: That's a good improvement, I am going to try using basic 20 second base containers with a powershell install to get mine running faster, can't be any worse than the 6 mins they take to pull at the moment.